# Java classpath when compiling and running

Tags: java, classpath

I have a directory MAIN/ with:

```
somelib.jar
someclass.java
job1.sh
job2.sh
subdir1/
subdir2/
```

In subdir1/ there is:

```
mainfile.java
```

In subdir2/ there is

```
mainfile.java
```

If I would like to compile and run either mainfile.java from the MAIN/ directory, how would I do this? Also, how do I prevent any confusion so the two different files mainfile.java don't intercept if I compile/run them around the same time? mainfile.java depends on somelib.jar and someclass.java

I tried:

```
javac -cp `pwd`:someclass.java:somelib.jar subdir1/mainfile.java
java -cp `pwd`:somelib.jar:subdir1/ mainfile
```

but this only works if I do this for one subdirectory. If I do this for both around the same time, then I get an error based on somelib.jar.

Comment: Well why do you have three files called `mainfile.java` to start with? Do they declare classes in different packages? It's not clear why you're trying to put a *source* file on the classpath to start with.

Comment: Sorry, I mainly use C++. so I might not be using the correct terminology. mainfile.java is like the source code which uses someclass.java. someclass.java is like a header file (it just defines a class called mammal).

Comment: Frankly, change the organization. Having jar file, shell scripts, and Java source files in the same folder is a complete mess. `scripts`: for scripts. `src`: for Java source files. Classes should belong to packages, and the package tree should match exactly with the folder tree inside src. `lib`: for jar files. `build`or `classes`or `bin`: for compiled .class files.

Comment: Regardless of what's in `mainfile.java`, a classpath is meant to contain *compiled* files, not source files.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh sorry, I'm fairly new to this :/ So, would it be better if I put someclass.java in the subdirectories?

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow JB Nizet's guidance.